# How to mutate a array on state in a redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, reducers

State prior to change looks like this:

```
foreignBases: [
  {
    base: {
      id: "5b8125ec14bb4f35f8f01aa9",
      ...
    },
    baseuser: {
      userId: "tester1",
      ...
    }
  },
  { base: { ... }, baseuser: { ... } }
]
```

via dispatch the user changes a boolean in the `baseuser` key to `true`, the reducer is then supposed to update the state for this particular key value pair, but I can't seem to get it right with this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < state.foreignBases.length; i++) {
  if (action.baseUser.created === state.foreignBases[i].baseuser.created) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      foreignBases: [
        ...state.foreignBases,
        {
          base: { ...state.foreignBases[i].base },
          baseuser: action.baseUser
        }
      ]
    });
}
```

This just adds another object to the state, when I really just need to replace one boolean of baseuser in one object

Comment: Do you mind posting your action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Be sure to check below for updates.*

The spread operator is re-inserting the entire foreignBases, and then you're adding another object with what I assume is your intended mutation.

I'm thinking you mean something like this (untested)

```
for (let i = 0; i < state.foreignBases.length; i++) {
  if (action.baseUser.created === state.foreignBases[i].baseuser.created) {
    let foreignBases = [...state.foreignBases];
    foreignBases[i].baseuser = action.baseUser;
    return Object.assign({}, state, {foreignBases});
  }
}
```

***Update***: @devserkan reminded me that the spread operator "does not do a deep copy", which is a no-no in Redux! So I went looking for [the updating an item in an array official pattern](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array), which I believe is applied like this (again, untested):

```
let foreignBases = state.foreignBases.map((foreignBase) => {
  if (action.baseUser.created === foreignBase.baseuser.created) {
    return {action.baseUser};
  } else {
    return foreignBase
  }
});
return Object.assign({}, state,  { 
   ...foreignBase,
   baseuser: action.baseUser
});
```

***Update 2***: @devserkan in the comments again contributes valuable insight, this time fixing the original for loop, by nesting in parts of the state object. Which is similar to mutation. This approach avoids that and allows you to still use a for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < state.foreignBases.length; i++) {
  if (action.baseUser.created === state.foreignBases[i].baseuser.created) {
    const newItem = {
      ...state.foreignBases[i],
      baseuser: action.baseUser
    };
    const newforeignBases = Object.assign([], state.foreignBases, {
      [i]: newItem
    });
    return Object.assign({}, state, { foreignBases: newforeignBases });
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, and works like a charm. Thank you.
Could you explain a little bit WHY this works? What is your thought process behind this?

Comment: Just a reminder. Spread syntax does not do a deep copy. So when you change the copied object's properties, the original one mutates, too.

Comment: @Helle Does the new pattern help make this make more sense? My thoughts were basically to create the foreignBases object before doing the object assign. You'd already found the right foreignBase, it just needed to be modified slightly before being added to state, but of course, you're not to modify the state directly.

Comment: I was going to provide an answer like this. `map` is the tool here. No for loops, no direct mutating the state. But, there are two problems here :) `return {action.baseUser};` this does not work since the syntax is wrong. `return {baseuser: action.baseUser};` is the right one. But this time we lose `base` in the item. So: `return { ...foreignBase, baseuser: action.baseUser };` Nice solution by the way.

Comment: The new pattern in conjunction with @devserkan 's latest `return` comment makes it work. To reiterate the solution to myself, we can't have my solution to begin with because it mutates state directly. In contrast, Both of your guys' solutions together do not change the state directly, but map a new one as a copy which then becomes state

Comment: Actually, your code does not mutate the state but it is somehow wrong. You are populating `foreignBase` into it at some point of your code. Also, you can't set the state easily with a for loop. For those kinds of situations try to use `map`, `filter`.

Comment: Here how can you do that similar to your code: `for (let i = 0; i < state.foreignBases.length; i++) {
  if (action.baseUser.created === state.foreignBases[i].baseuser.created) {
    const newItem = { ...state.foreignBases[i], baseuser: action.baseUser};
    const newforeignBases = Object.assign([], state.foreignBases, { [i]: newItem });
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      foreignBases: newforeignBases
    });
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks for the update @devserkan. Since the original answer has now been improved upon twice by the comments, I thought I'd mark this as a community wiki answer.

Comment: Actually, I liked very much your previous answer. It just needs a simple fix. I provided the for loop version in the comments here since @Helle tried to understand the logic. But, instead of a for loop, I would prefer your `map` version :)